# Memberr - Automatic Cancellation feature?

Tags: membrr

In the [documentation](http://www.membrr.com/docs/subscriptions), I see that you can cancel manually via {exp:membrr:cancel} tag.

But is there a way to cancel automatically?

Basically, what I was looking for is that if a membrr profile that I have is deleted, I would want it to automatically cancel all subscriptions that profile has subscribed to.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it possible by creating an extension with the hook "member_delete".
Within this extension, you can call the Membrr cancel subscription method by passing member's  subscription ids.

The cancellation code would be something like:

```
$sub_id = x; // Get the member's subscription id with query
require PATH_THIRD.'membrr/class.membrr_ee.php';
$membrr = new Membrr_EE;
$membrr->CancelSubscription($sub_id);
```

It would work. Although, I would suggest you to test at your end.

Comment: Sorry I missed this. Will test and see if this will work.